# Binning Dataframe column based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series which is a basic time-series dataset, call it `data`. I then have columns created from this time series, which is an `n` period rolling moving average plus rolling variances, e.g. `mu +/- k*sigma` where `k` is an integer. I would like to then put these `2k+1` series side by side, and bin the original data based on where it falls in these columns (i.e. compute a z-score). E.g., if `data.iloc[0] < mu.ilo[0] -3*sigma.iloc[0]`, then we have that `binned_df.iloc[0] = -3` .

Is there any quick, systematic way of doing this that supports arbitrary values of `k`? I know of `np.select`, but I can't think of a way to generalize that to arbitrarily many `k` without writing everything out by hand.

Here is a toy example:

| -1sigma | data | 1 sigma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | -3 | 1 |
| -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

The new table would then have the entries:

| bins |
| --- |
| -1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

Why? Because in the first case, the data is -3 whereas the left limit (-1 sigma) is -2, and because -3 < -2, we bin it as the lowest possible (-1). In the second case, the data falls between -1 sigma and 1 sigma, so it is in the middle bin, 0. And finally, for the third, the data is in the upper extremity (greater than 1 sigma).

This is a simple example (2 fences, and thus 3 bins), ideally I'd like to do it with more fences (more sigmas essentially).

Comment: Hard to understand unless you give a working example.

Comment: @Mainland I have added a short example, let me know if it makes things more understandable

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly: I think it would be easier if you add a column with the mean and another with the absolute value of 1 sigma. Then you can just calculate what you need to add to the binned column: (data - mu) // sigma

Comment: @rubikscube09 You can accept or upvote the answer if it worked well

Comment: @xkudsraw - unfortunately you've only put it as a comment!